# Sending email using gmail is taking too long in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am done with my set up . mail sending is also working properly but taking to much time to send the mail.

Plz tell me way by which i can fix this issue .

Comment: What does "too much time" mean? What is your expectation, and how long does it actually take?

Comment: And how do you send it? Please read up on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can answer your questino meaningfully.

Comment: Sending emails takes some time even if you do it with the local mail function. Use queues/workers for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you run multiple workers in parallel. If your SMTP server's connection takes a second, you'll send 10 emails per second if you have 10 workers. But check with your IT to see if they aren't throttling by IP addresses.

But honestly, either your IT looks at why their SMTP server can't send emails fast enough, or you look at using an external server to do your mass mailing.

So i suggest you that please change your SMTP Server. It may be help you.

For more information :

https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/6e7knm/mail_facade_very_slow_sending_email_with_local/

https://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 3):

Use queues https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues
The mail will be added to queue and sent later. Does not need client to wait for request to finish.